# html formatted as such out of jquery html method

Tags: jquery, html, format

Data is a html string read from a text file. The following is the content of the text file:

```
<span style="font-size: 60%;">Aquests són els apunts del curs de xinès bàsic que VAIG fer del 12 d'abril al 23 de juny de 2012 a la Cambra de Comerç de Valls (40 hores). </span>
```

I want to put this html inside an html paragraph like shown below:

```
$("#myp").html(Data);
```

but what actually comes out in the web page is not interpreted html i.e. the tags are shown and the style is not applied. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of HTML element is 'myp'?

Comment: works here: http://jsfiddle.net/TYEKC/

Comment: @JonRed i suppose a `<p>` tag

Comment: It's look ok, problem is somewhere else, maybe you escaped html string in `Data`.

Comment: check in console what is actually Data

Comment: well I think you were right.. the python script that writes the data to the file makes this operation before writing it: "text = cgi.escape(text) # Avoid script injection escaping the user input". I've commented this line and written the text file again. Now it works though I still do not understand why.. and what escaping is Thank you!

Comment: @marcel3 Read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was inside the python script that retrieved the data from the text file. The python script was escaping the user input to avaid script injection. I solved it by removing the escape () sentence.

Answer (score 0):

`$("#myp").html($(Data));` should do the trick

Comment: doing that the paagraph gets blank

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted by something as simple as:

```
document.getElementById('myp').innerHTML = Data;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TYEKC/1/  (borrowed from @roasted above.  Which also does work)